# WSO2 indirect Endpoint inside Failover Group

Tags: wso2, endpoint, failover, wso2-esb

Is it possible to use an Indirect Enpoint inside the definition of a Failover Group endpoint?
I mean something like this:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="failOver2">
    <failover>
    <endpoint key="LBEndpoint" />   
    </failover>
</endpoint>
```

Where LBEndpoint is a load balance endpoint defined and saved previously in the registry.

When i click on the Save button... all my configuration is lost and the fail over group comes back into this form:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="failOver2">
   <failover/>
</endpoint>
```

Is this a bug? Inside the WSO2 ESB documentation it says that all this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try editing synapse configuration directly? That is, not using sequence editor UI. Go to sourceview and manually edit and point the endpoint key in failoverendpoint.

Comment: Right! On file System yes, the xml contains the right configuration. But it's senseless for my purpose. I mean... i need to save the configuration on the registry and to access it for checks or modifications, or accessing it runtime from my code. So, is it a bug?